# Web Conferencing programs turn off Dolby Advanced Audio

Tags: audio, skype, acer-aspire

Programs like GoToMeeting, Zoom, Skype turn off `Dolby Advanced Audio` (DAA) on my laptop when a call starts (why?).

[image]

This makes the sound volume drop significantly. Later I have to turn it on manually.

Actually, the laptop's speakers can't produce the maximum volume when DAA is turned off or not installed.

Is it possible to make DAA not react to the calls or replace it with some other volume booster?

The laptop is Acer Aspire 5755G.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All web conference app requires acoustic echo cancellation to eliminate massive feedbacks.

The only way to use acoustic echo cancellation is to turn off all other audio enhancements.